# a signed resource has been added, modified, or deleted during installation of my adhoc

Tags: ios6, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.5, ad-hoc-distribution

I am really frustrated that making my adhoc app install to my device. I have got this problem in this app. I used a team provision file (i.e. with "*" as identifier) to build all my apps for adhoc. it works fine for all other apps. just this app, when i install, it pops up a message "a signed resource has been added modified or deleted" and getting the following message in the organizer console log.

installd[53] : 0x303000 handle_install: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/mygame.ipa" requested by mobile_installation_proxy
Jul 25 03:52:35 Chaus-iPhone-5 installd[53] : 0x303000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app com.mycom.mobile.mygame
installd[53] : Jul 25 03:52:36  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
installd[53] : 0x303000 verify_signer_identity: MISValidateSignatureAndCopyInfo failed for /var/tmp/install_staging.8gaMZw/foo_extracted/Payload/mygame.app/mygame: 0xe8008017
installd[53] : 0x303000 do_preflight_verification: Could not verify executable at /var/tmp/install_staging.8gaMZw/foo_extracted/Payload/mygame.app
 installd[53] : 0x303000 install_application: Could not preflight application install
 mobile_installation_proxy[6989] : 0x3ceefb78 MobileInstallationInstall: failed with -1
 mobile_installation_proxy[6989] : handle_install: Installation failed
  installd[53] : 0x303000 handle_install: API failed

please let me know what I should do to fix this problem. Thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I found this is the solution:

go to your project in terminal and type:

find . -name "._*" -delete