# Ad Hoc distribution app is gray, after transfer from iTunes to iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes, adhoc

I've been develoming an app and is at a stage now where i want to make other ppl able to tst out my app. I've created a Ad Hoc provisioning profile and build an .ipa file with archives. After that i added the .ipa file to iTunes apps library and sync'ed iTunes with my iPhone. After this i look at my phone and the app is grayed out and if i press it it writes installing, but never gets done installing.

I've tried to recreate my certificat + profile + ipa file. And i did uninstall the debug app that was on my device, before i transferred the one with a ad hoc profile.

Ov, and as a side note the app works 100% if i just build a release build through xCode, and use xCode to transfer it, but i NEED that .ipa file so that solution wont cut it for me.

What am i doing wrong here, plzzz help?^^

SOLUTION: Don't use " "(space) in the file name of the .ipa file

Answer (score 3):

Are you 'distributing' the application and saving for ad-hoc/enterprise deployment ? The chances are the provisioning profile you created doesn't have the device UDID in it. Check on the dev portal that your ad hoc profile has that device included.

Comment: Isent the point of AD hoc that you dont need an UDID? so everyone can test your app?

Comment: That's only with Enterprise Distribution. Which is a separate £200/Year subscription.

Comment: no adHoc let you have 100 UDIDs no more. if you want an unlimited number, you can use in-house distribution, but this is an other topic :)

Comment: If i look under devices in my AD HOC profile theres one called iPhone 5

Comment: Is it ticked ? and is that the device you are trying to install the app on ?

Comment: Yes its ticked and yes its an iPhone5 im install it on

Comment: So when you archive it in Xcode have you got this provisioning profile selected in the build settings ?

Comment: Try installing the iPad using the iPhone Configurator application, This may give you a more specific error.

Comment: yes i got my AD HOC profile selected, ill try iPhone Configurator application

Comment: This version crashes under mavericks when trying to install applications. An alternative is to open Xcode organiser and drag the iPad to the applications option under the connected device.

Comment: If i drag and drop the .ipa to the iPhone in organizer it copy's it when its done it says "A signed resource has been added, modified or deleted." after i click ok to the warning the app is not copyed at all:(

Comment: Not sure what's going on, it's a rather convoluted process provisioning. My suggestion would be to delete all profiles/certificates and start again from fresh...?

Comment: I might be on to something look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847777/a-signed-resource-has-been-added-modified-or-deleted-during-installation-of-my
like he got a team profile with * i do to

Comment: hmmm the first error in the console is now clear when im not using itunes so here it is: Please include the kCFBundleIdentifierKey in the options dictionary when installing an app.

Comment: I've startd a new post to try to get an answer to this error i found. Thx for all the help even though it dident work, it was still a little help to get me moved on to this new error:(

Comment: That * just indicates a wildcard so you can use the same provisioning profile for lots of different apps. This can't be done if you're using app specific permissions, push notifications etc ...

Comment: the kCFBundleIdentifierKey is an error caused if you edited the Bundle Identifier property in the app.plist to an invalid one.

Comment: Thing is i havent edited my bundle^^ I've tried to though just to see what will happen. When i do i get a compile error that the bundle ID isent matching the profile

Comment: App ID is GolfBox Golfers DK (dk.golferportal.golfersDK)

Comment: Bundle ID in xCode: dk.golferportal.golfersDK

Comment: Not really sure, has to be the provisioning profile... Try and re create it from scratch ...

Comment: Okey all this fuss was all because i used " " (space) in the .ipa file name

Comment: So it's working now ? That shouldn't make a difference ... oh well. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

If you instal the app from xCode and you can see the log in the console debugger, that's mean that you are not in "distribution" mode but in debug mode.
Verify your provisioning profile and the build mode.

Comment: i cant see the condole debugger cause im in release mode