# Can't install iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, installation, ipa

I'm trying to test out an .ipa file but when i install it with xCode i get the following error: Please include the kCFBundleIdentifierKey in the options dictionary when installing an app.

I've checked and re checked my bundle ID and it is matching the ad hoc profile i got so what's wrong here? if i install the app with iTunes the app icon just gets grayed out and if i press the app to open it, it just writes "installing..." and keeps saying that.

Any help is appreciated, been stuck with this for 5 hours now:(

Heres my .plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"     "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>English</string>
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>GolfBox</string>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>GP Mobil</string>
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
<string></string>
<key>CFBundleIcons</key>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>icon.png</string>
            <string>icon@2x.png</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>dk.golferportal.golfersDK</string>
<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>dk.golferportal.golfersDK</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>APPL</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.7</string>
<key>CFBundleSignature</key>
<string>????</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1.7.0</string>
<key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
<true/>
<key>NSMainNibFile</key>
<string>MainWindow</string>
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
</array>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

SOLUTION: Don't use " "(space) in the file name of the .ipa file

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ad Hoc distribution app is gray, after transfer from iTunes to iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20973028/ad-hoc-distribution-app-is-gray-after-transfer-from-itunes-to-iphone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your app doesn't have a bundle identifier

Do this:

1. Right click on your .plist file,
2. Click open as -> Source Code
3. Copy and paste that code onto your post so we can take a look at your plist configuration. Chances are something is missing and that something needs to be added such as your bundle identifier key

Once youve updated your post and i've had a chance to take a look at it, I can update my post to help correct your situation

**UPDATE**

It turns out that the problem occurred due to a space character found in the filename which must not occur. Taking out the space character solves the problem.

Comment: My .plist is now in the post

Comment: Ok I've checked your .plist, nothing seems to be wrong there.
Lets try something else, try creating a new .ipa with a simple view based application with no code at all - just the basic app - and see if you are successful then or if you are finding that problem again. If the .IPA is successful then I would suggest porting over JUST your code and view controllers to the new app.. It might be a dirty option but it could possibly save you time as I cant say anything else from the information we know atm

Comment: when i create a new project i works...... bummer cause this is a REALLY big app. gonna be a pain if this really is the best solution. Anyway BIG thanks!

Comment: @user2408952 No problem buddy. Im glad it atleast works for you in a new app. Im sorry that we couldnt find the actual solution to your problem, but I have suggested an alternative solution for you which might be quicker.

Comment: @user2408952 If this helped and works for you do mark the answer as correct. Thanks and goodluck

Comment: What works was creating a new project and archive it to my iPhone. I dont know if it will work after porting all my files, as i said before its a big project. So it will take me some time to port it into the new project^^ when and if it works, then ill mark it as answered^^

Comment: Okey i cant belive this is no were to be found but what worked for me was this. the ipa file MUST NOT CONTAIN " " (a space in the filename)

Comment: Yes, you cant have space characters in your plist file name. I didnt know you had a space character in your filename. Anyway answer has been updated accordingly

Comment: its not i my .plist name its in my .ipa file name^^